# accessing user control in class file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls

I want to access a usercontrol in my class file not in aspx.cs.i need to typecast it using ASP.usercontrol_ascx type but i cant access ASP namespace from my .cs file..how to typecast the usercontrol??

Thnx....

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Every user control is inherited from `UserControl` class.</strike>

So it is possible to access your user control like this

```
UserControl userControl = (UserControl) new MyBrandUserControl();
```

**Do This**

In that case you have to *expand hierarchy*. What you have to do is, create a class `MyUserControlBase` which will inherit from `UserControl` class, and your `MyBrandUserControl` user control will inherit from `MyUserControlBase` class.

Now, your properties will reside in `MyUserControlBase`, and you can cast it like:

```
MyUserControlBaseuserControl = (MyUserControlBase) new MyBrandUserControl();
```

Please let me know whether if you are not looking for this.

Comment: i have added public properties to usercontrol so i need that specific control typecasted to access those properties.